# How to set up an Exchange Email account in Windows Phone

Tags: exchange

I am trying to add my institutional Email in Windows Phone. I think the Email system is Exchange, however, the top-left corner of my inbox reads Outlook Web Access. Windows phone cannot log in the Email system with the information I provided.  To add the account I selected **Add an Account>Exchange**, and then went on to enter my email address and password. Login failed, and then I chose Advanced and entered the following information:
(Based on what I use to log-in on a web browser)
User name: the part after "/": myuname
Password:***
Domain: the part before "/" (here it is my college domain).
Server: the address I see when I open my inbox in web browser is https://webmail.mycollge.ac.ir/Exchange.  I entered https://webmail.mycollge.ac.ir and https://webmail.mycollge.ac.ir/Exchange and webmail.mycollge.ac.ir but all of them failed to log in.
Also selecting/deselecting "Server requires encrypted (SSL) connection didn't help either.   I get this error (figure 1):

[image]

Here is a screenshot of my Web mail login page:
[image]

I have no problem with web login as I enter mycollege.ac.ir\myuname for Domain\user name and my password in the Password.